# How could an attack work against Kosh?

Tags: babylon-5

How would the poisoning in the premiere work?

And later:

> How did the Shadows kill Kosh? Weren't the Vorlons beings of energy? How could you kill that?

Explanation about duplicate question:

I want to point that the main question is about

> Kosh dead,

being the poisoning a related question added as an afterthought. So it isnt duplicate because only the poison part had been answered.

Comment: Antimater annihilate mater.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OI4kah6Rp4 - "*Where are all the rest? They fell ill and died, were injured and died, or just left."*

Comment: Poor mater. He's just trying to be a good tow truck and friend to Lightning McQueen.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi StackExchange. The second question about how could anybody poison (or even know how to poison) a Vorlon has already been asked on StackExchange. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163157/how-would-anybody-know-how-to-poison-a-vorlon?rq=1 You might want to edit your question to remove that part so it does not get flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @LincolnMan: I did it. Thanks.

Comment: welp - spoiler alert : \ - I know it's an old show, but with it reappearing on Amazon Prime in the past few months, I started it having only seen bits and pieces during original run and in the early 2000's SciFi syndication. Given the uptick in B5 questions lately, I suspect many are in the same boat. Thus, I'm spoiler tagging the question

Comment: @NKCampbell - That's a fair point. Kosh's identify and fate is a pretty big reveal.

Comment: FWIW you _should not_ delete a post because it is a duplicate. See the [relevant meta on this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7943/58193).

Comment: Your latest edit invalidated my answer (again). If you want to add a comment about why it's not a duplicate,, go for it, but changing it into a new question isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @Valorum: I hope that this solve the problem definitely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was addressed by JMS in [an interview](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/044.html) on the Midwinter site.

> **Q.** ***Was he really poisoned, or just pretending? ("The Gathering")***
>
> **JMS:** *No, he wasn't faking it. Understand that their appearance as a being of light is only how they want to appear; **they are life forms much the same as many others, and can be poisoned if one knows the right combination of substances.***

So, although the Vorlons have the capacity to turn themselves into *beings of light* (temporarily?), that doesn't make them functionally immortal against what Lorien describes as '[illness or injury](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OI4kah6Rp4)', especially in fisticuffs against another being that is largely the same as themselves.

---

JMS [noted](http://www.jmsnews.com/messages/message?id=10421) that although the Vorlon appear as swirling light to us, there's also a "physicality" to them that allows them to be touched and to touch.

> Yes, that's a Vorlon...and there was a physicality to them, shown by
> the fact that it could strike out and hit things. It's not a ghost or
> anything of that nature, it can be hurt and killed.

Comment: Ah! That's explain a lot. Including the scene of the last? episode of season 4 a million years after the events of the serie.

Comment: @Spkit2000 - Indeed. The human, having evolved into becoming an "elder race" is able to turn itself into some sort of glowing psychic energy thingy. But its base state still seems to be a living breathing human

Comment: Hey! FYI! Your answer is about poisoning Vorlons, but the question was edited so it no longer mentions the poison attempt on Kosh. The question is about how the Shadows tried to kill Kosh.

Comment: @LincolnMan - Indeed. Since the two are closely related, I've rolled back the question to what OP originally intended

Comment: But why roll back an edit that the OP made? If the OP made the edit, then result are clearly what the OP intended. If somebody else made the edit, then you might have a case for rolling back.

Comment: @LincolnMan - If a user makes a material change that invalidates existing answers, we tend to roll those back, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Valorum and LincolnMan: As the OP I checked the different versions. I think that there isn't any problem. Any way, I tweaked it a little.

Comment: @LincolnMan: I changed the question because one part of it had been already answered. You are right, I didnt have to do it. :(